# I have an error message when running my test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

> ```
>  what-is-a-test Message gives the name and height:
>
>  Error: Expected 'is 34 inches tall' to include 'Susan'
>   at assert (node_modules/expect/lib/assert.js:29:9)
>   at Expectation.toInclude (node_modules/expect/lib/Expectation.js:215:28)
>   at Context.it (test/index-test.js:19:29)
> ```

I'm not sure what needs to be fixed. Please help.

Comment: can you share code ?

Answer (score 0):

You understand how to read tests, now it's time to run the tests. We've made it fairly easy. In the same terminal that you used to write nodejs tests.js or nodejs index.js now, you just need to write learn. That's it! No matter what the lab, our Learn command will figure out where you are and run the appropriate tests and give you results.

Speaking of results... let's talk about how to read the results that tests give you.

**Reading Results of Tests**

If we run learn in our terminal right now, you'll get a bunch of failed tests. It will look something like this:

**Output from running learn in Terminal**

```
> js-functions-lab@0.1.0 test /Users/joe/Documents/Documents/flatiron/js-what-is-a-test-lab
> mocha -R mocha-multi --reporter-options nyan=-,json=.results.json

 0   -_-__,------,
 3   -_-__|  /\_/\
 0   -_-_~|_( x .x)
     -_-_ ""  ""

  0 passing (612ms)
  3 failing

  1) what-is-a-test Name returns "Susan":

      Error: Expected 'Joe' to equal 'Susan'
      + expected - actual

      -Joe
      +Susan

      at assert (node_modules/expect/lib/assert.js:29:9)
      at Expectation.toEqual (node_modules/expect/lib/Expectation.js:81:30)
      at Context.it (test/index-test.js:6:26)

  2) what-is-a-test Height is less than 40:
     Error: Expected 74 to be less than 40
      at assert (node_modules/expect/lib/assert.js:29:9)
      at Expectation.toBeLessThan (node_modules/expect/lib/Expectation.js:156:28)
      at Context.it (test/index-test.js:13:28)

  3) what-is-a-test Message gives the name and height:
     Error: Expected ' is 74 inches tall' to include 'Joe'
      at assert (node_modules/expect/lib/assert.js:29:9)
      at Expectation.toInclude (node_modules/expect/lib/Expectation.js:215:28)
      at Context.it (test/index-test.js:19:29)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
Let's break this down a bit. If you look at the line under the cat (I love programmers) you'll see a summary of how the tests went:

0 passing (612ms)
3 failing
```

for more read data look at this link [js-what-is-a-test-lab-bootcamp-prep](https://github.com/learn-co-students/js-what-is-a-test-lab-bootcamp-prep-000)